# Pythonnet - Memory Management Errors

Tags: python, c#, memory-leaks, binding, python.net

### Environment

- Pythonnet version: 3.0.2
- Python version: 3.9
- Operating System: Windows 10
- .NET Runtime: .NET Framework 4.8

### Details

I am trying to open a large file through a .NET Framework DLL and access the data inside python.

### Scenario:

- Pythonnet is loaded inside the module in which I perform these operations.
- The C# Object is an attribute of a Python class.
- The python class has the _*del*_() method implemented in which I have to call a method, inside the C# class, right before destructing the object.
- I have added a log print in the C# Destructor to know when the CLR calls it.

### Errors

- In some cases, the CLR logs the destructor call before the _*del*_() of the python method is executed, so this is not a big deal because the method I have to call C# side is also called in the destructor, and I mange with exception handling the fact that the C# object is no longer there when the _*del*_() is executed. **Solvable But Not Nice(SEE EXAMPLE)**.
- In other cases, the python GC frees the memory before the Pythonnet.Runtime.Dll manages to deal with it, so in the function Python.Shutdow() (*Where you try to get pointers if you are familiar with the code*) you are trying to get rid of already freed memory areas( Sorry if it is a rough explanation but I do not have time and resources to do a full reverse engineering of this problem). I have solved it by adding try and catches here and there inside Python.Shoutdown() function and by checking null pointers. **VERY BAD**

**If someone with more experience than me about this tool sees any issues in what I am trying to do python side I will happily fix my code, otherwise if you think this might be a real problem I will do a pull request with my corrections so everyone can get a benefit from them.**

**UPDATE ADDED CODE**

- Python Class Code:

```
import pythonnet
from pythonnet import load
load("netfx")
import clr
from time import time
try:
    clr.AddReference('FileManager.Library')
    import FileManager.Library
except System.IO.FileNotFoundException:
    print("[File loader] DLL not found!")

class FileLoader:
    def __init__(self, filePath):
        self.dataLoader = FileManager.Library.FileReader(filePath)
        self.isClosed = False

    def load_data(self):
        return self.dataLoader.GetDataPoints()
    
    def close(self):
        self.dataLoader.Close()
        self.isClosed = True

    def __del__(self):
        print(f"[FileLoader - {time()}] Freeing memory!", flush=True)

        if not self.isClosed:
            self.close()
```

- Python Main:

```
from FileManager.FileLoader import FileLoader


if __name__ == "__main__":
    fl = FileLoader("data.csv")
    data = fl.load_data()
    print("Done!")
```

- C# ClassLibrary Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace FileManager.Library
{
    public class FileReader: IDisposable
    {
        private string filePath;
        private int objectId;
        private bool isDisposed = false;
        private List<DataPoint> fileContent;
        private DateTimeOffset dto = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.UtcNow);

        ~FileReader() {
            if(!isDisposed)
                Dispose();

            System.Console.WriteLine($"[C# -  {dto.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds().ToString()} ] Deleting {objectId}");
        }

        public FileReader(string filePath)
        {
            this.filePath = filePath;
            fileContent = new List<DataPoint>();
            objectId = this.GetHashCode();
            LoadFile();
        }

        private void LoadFile()
        {

            if (!File.Exists(filePath))
            {
                throw new FileNotFoundException($"Cannot open file{filePath}");
            }

            const Int32 BufferSize = 128;
            using (var fileStream = File.OpenRead(filePath))
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(fileStream, Encoding.UTF8, true, BufferSize))
            {
                String line;
                while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    var data = line.Split(',');
                    var dataPoint = new DataPoint((int)Convert.ToDouble(data[0]), Convert.ToDouble(data[1]));
                    fileContent.Add(dataPoint);
                }
                fileStream.Close();
            }
            
            return;
        }

        public DataPoint GetDataPoint(int i)
        {
            return fileContent[i];
        }

        public List<DataPoint> GetDataPoints()
        {
            return fileContent;
        }

        public void Dispose() {
            
            if (isDisposed) return;
            System.Console.WriteLine($"[C# - {dto.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds().ToString()}] Disoposing Obj {objectId}");
            isDisposed = true;
        }

        public void Close() {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Dummy things That I have to do before closing");
        }

    }
}
```

Running the python main above with the debugger works fine(also time stamps in correct order) but without the debugger I **ALWAYS** get the following error:

```
Dummy things That I have to do before closing
Done!
[C# - 1698683227427] Disoposing Obj 26765710
[C# -  1698683227427 ] Deleting 26765710
[FileLoader - 1698683227.5009353] Freeing memory!
Exception ignored in: <function FileLoader.__del__ at 0x00000158F00920D0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "FileLoader.py", line 30, in __del__
TypeError: 'MethodObject' object is not callable
```

**Where am I wrong? How Can I fix it?**
***Note 1:** Obviously I do not want to try catch it I want it to work properly* 
***Note 2:** Same main in C# no errors at all*

Answer (score 0):

I think this happens because you let Python objects referencing .NET live to program termination. Wrap your main module in a function like this:

```py
def main():
  ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Then all objects you create in main will be destroyed before Python shutdown, and the problem should go away.

Alternatively explicitly `del` them before printing "Done".

Comment: Yes, I Noticed that but I did not think about the del bit, seems it solves the issue.